# How can I check if exist like minimum one array in each panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, module, each

I can create N panels, for example I have three now.

the panels are each white rectangle.

In each panel I can create N arrays, in this case the arrays are rows for a dynamic table.

(this work when I click in a button)

now I need check if exist one array like minimum in each panel.

example: I create a row in panel 1, now I click the button, the message would be "error, complete the panel 2 or if I create a row in panel 2 "complete the panel 1 ".

I work dynamically and with modules.

What is the logic to do that in jq javascript?

this code in this module would validate:

```
validarBotonEnviar: function(idSeccion){

    var self = this;
    var aDataTareas = self.aListadoTareas[idSeccion]; 

    $.each(aDataTareas, function(index,value) {

    if (aDataTareas.length > 0){

        oData = {};
        oData.datos = aDataTareas;
        oData.estado = true;

        self.publishers("validBoton",oData);

    }else{

        oData = {};
        oData.seccion = idSeccion;
        oData.aceptar = false;

        self.publishers("validBoton",oData);
        }
    });
```

and in this module I have the method with the button

```
AccionBotonEnviar: function(estado){

var self = this;

    $("#btn_enviar_formulario_id").click(function(){

        if(estado === true){

          console.info("todo ok");

        } else {

         console.info("todo mal");
        }
    });
},
```

http://www.uppic.com/uploads/14298803131.jpg

Comment: we need to see your code :)

Comment: You seem to be mixing terms `array` , `rows` and `panels` and it is very confusing without seeing any code as to what you are actually referring to

Comment: i edit with more information , thanks

Comment: A simple demo in jsfiddle.net would help. We can't see your html